How to conditionally format multiple cells to ignore the formula and format only based on the value in Excel?
I have a worksheet with a large number of formulas in it. Each formula references another cell in another worksheet (ex. =HARASH!$U$16). I want to conditionally format each cell based on the cell value with three colour gradients (red, green, light green). D33 contains the value 1.25. If the cell is LESS THAN 5% of 1.25/D33, it should be red. If it EQUALS 5% of 1.25/D33, it should be light green. If it is GREATER THAN 1.25, it should be green.
This works fine, except the last one: GREATER THAN. The format is applied to all the blank cells, which contain only a formula such as =HARASH!$U$16 but no actual value. Does Excel read the formula =HARASH!$U$16) as >1.25? How can I make it ignore the formula and only format the value if there is one?

Conditional formatting is based on the value. What does HARASH!$U$16? contain? Just a guess, but if you're working with a blank string "", that is a value, and "" is greater than 1.25. Continuing with this scenario, consider using ISNUMBER.

Yes, it would be " ", but I didn't think that would be greater than 1.25. Instead of writing out conditional formatting for IsNumber(), would it be faster and more efficient to use a VBA function? I am not sure how to use IsNumber() and apply it to multiple cells at once in conditional formatting.

It is greater than 1.25. Put =" ">1.25 in a random cell to verify. Ah, I'd have to research if it's possible to apply a gradient format using a rule based on a formula. Alternately, create three rules: one for red, one for green, one for light green. You need to use a rule based on a formula. e.g. =AND(ISNUMBER(A1),A1<0.05*D33) for red.

Could I apply that kind of formula to multiple cells (ex. a range) at once? Can IsNumber() evaluate a range or only a cell?

Conditional formatting is evaluated cell-by-cell. Yes you can apply it to multiple cells. If you want the D33 reference to remain constant, change it to $D$33.

I meant how would I write a conditional formatting with IsNumber() and apply it to a range of cells? The formatting might be evaluated on a cell-by-cell basis, but how would I write a single formula that evaluates a range of cells like that? For example, would it be =AND(ISNUMBER(D5:D9),D5:D(<0.05*D33). That seems wrong to me. I am just trying to avoid writing out the same formula a million times.

You'd use relative references (like D5). Excel is smart enough to "update" the relative reference in the context of each individual cell.
